# Ошибка Git: remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master

Tags: git

Вроде перечитал интернет, немного не пойму. Якобы не будет ошибки с bare-репозиторием. Меня, в принципе, устроит и такой репозиторий. Как лучше то сделать?

Comment: Я ничего не понял, честно. Насколько понимаю, ошибка говорит о том, что в удаленном репозитории, в который производится пуш, указанный бранч является чекаутным (с т.з. гита - редактируемым в данный момент), поэтому его обновить нельзя. Для разрешения этой ситуации достаточно перейти на другой бранч в удаленном репозитории.

Answer (score 2):

У вас похоже не bare репозиторий, а обычный. Можно перейти в detached HEAD состояние:

```
git checkout --detach
```